# Read/Write to c drive?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to read/write to the C:\ drive and it's directories with Adobe Air? if so how? I've only seen examples using the desktop or user directories with resolvePath().

Comment: Try it without using `resolvePath()` but instead use `yourFile.nativePath = "C:\\myFolder\\file.txt"`. Make sure the user running your air app has access to the directory too.

Comment: How can I check if my app has permission to access these files? I'll need administrative access I believe because I'll be installing files in the System32 folder.

Comment: lol, it had to be one of those locked down system folders :) You can put your code in a try catch block and if you catch a securityError you know you do not have permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to require the program to be ran with admin privilages?

Comment: I've tried just reading a file off the root "C:\myfile.txt" and I keep getting the error "Error #3003: File or directory does not exist." I've also wrapped it with a try-catch, and nothing different.

Comment: Why the bloody hell would you want to install files to sys32? Any computer-savvy person will now frown upon you if you try to modify their sys32 folder.

Comment: Actually, I found out I don't have to. It looks like the application that needs them will use the dll's I needed to install from within it's root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
var file : File = new File("c:/file.txt");

// Add a new File
var fs : FileStream = new FileStream;
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTFBytes("Hello");

fs.close();
```

Comment: I've tried my code before posting and it worked well. So you probably have a right problem.

Comment: you should probably say permission problem

Comment: Probably ^^', my english is so bad.

Comment: i've tried using the applicationDirectory, but that does the same thing. Shouldn't I be able to use at least that?

Comment: No, you can't write to app directory through resolvePath (you will get a SecurityError). Try File.applicationStorageDirectory, this is the one you should be abble to write into

Comment: nope. applicationStorageDirectory doesn't work either. same error

Comment: wait, i think i found the issue. I was using a slash in the beginning: resolvePath("/MyFile.ext").